# End Sub after closing a windows for causes Excel to crash, why?

Tags: vb.net, excel, vsto

The following sub in my com-addin does not cause any problems:

```
Private Sub MonthCalendar1_DateChanged(sender As Object, e As Windows.Forms.DateRangeEventArgs) Handles MonthCalendar1.DateChanged
        Dim ExcelApp As Excel.Application = CType(AddinExpress.MSO.ADXAddinModule.CurrentInstance, AddinModule).ExcelApp
        ExcelApp.ActiveCell.Value = MonthCalendar1.SelectionStart.Date
    End Sub
```

The following sub however, where I have added a Me.Close() statement, causes Excel to crash. What might the reason be?

```
Private Sub MonthCalendar1_DateChanged(sender As Object, e As Windows.Forms.DateRangeEventArgs) Handles MonthCalendar1.DateChanged
        Dim ExcelApp As Excel.Application = CType(AddinExpress.MSO.ADXAddinModule.CurrentInstance, AddinModule).ExcelApp
        ExcelApp.ActiveCell.Value = MonthCalendar1.SelectionStart.Date
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
```

EDIT: Maybe my code triggers some other event in my code to execute and that causes Excel to crash? Is it possible to pause execution at the start of any event? Since I don't know which event might be called, I would't know where to add a breakpoint.

Comment: I would try to close the Excel.Application BEFORE you close your form.

Comment: You can debug the code line by line and check where the execution goes after Me.Close()

Comment: I don't want to close the Excel application. The Excel application should stay open.

Comment: How can I do that Pankti Shah? When I press F11, it doesn't show me any other code executing. Excel just crashes.

Comment: Try using the [Hide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.hide(v=vs.110).aspx) method instead.

Comment: Okay, I will post it as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Hide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.hide(v=vs.110).aspx) method instead. It seems the DateChanged event handler is not the best place for such calls.